# list inside list

Tags: c#, xmldocument, xmlnode

I know its a lot code... sorry for that....my list class is like this..

```
public class XMLList
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Link { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public DateTime pubDate { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string dcCreator { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string GUID { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public Int32 wpPostId { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string wpStatus { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public Int32 wpMenuOrd { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Category { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public List<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
}

public class Comment
{
    [DataMember]
    public Int32 wpCmtId { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string wpCmtAuthor { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string wpCmtAuthorEmail { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string wpCmtAuthorURL { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public Int64 wpCmtAuthorIP { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public DateTime wpCmtAuthorDate { get; set; }
}
```

my c# code is like this

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(@"xml\willowcreekassociationblog.wordpress.xml");
//Get Channel Node
XmlNode channelNode = doc.SelectSingleNode("rss/channel");
if (channelNode != null)
{
    //Add NameSpace
    XmlNamespaceManager nameSpace = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
    nameSpace.AddNamespace("excerpt", "http://wordpress.org/export/1.2/excerpt/");
    nameSpace.AddNamespace("content", "http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/");
    nameSpace.AddNamespace("dc", "http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/");
    nameSpace.AddNamespace("wfw", "http://wellformedweb.org/CommentAPI/");
    nameSpace.AddNamespace("wp", "http://wordpress.org/export/1.2/");

    //Parse each item
    foreach (XmlNode itemNode in channelNode.SelectNodes("item"))
    {
        objrssItem.Add(rssItem);
        rssItem.GUID = itemNode.SelectSingleNode("guid").InnerText;
        rssItem.Title = itemNode.SelectSingleNode("title").InnerText;
        rssItem.dcCreator = itemNode.SelectSingleNode("dc:creator", nameSpace).InnerText;
        rssItem.Link = itemNode.SelectSingleNode("link").InnerText;
        rssItem.pubDate = DateTime.Parse(itemNode.SelectSingleNode("pubDate").InnerText);
        rssItem.ContentEncoded = itemNode.SelectSingleNode("content:encoded", nameSpace).InnerText;

        XmlNode cNode = doc.SelectSingleNode("rss/channel/item");
        foreach (XmlNode commentNode in cNode.SelectNodes("wp:comment", nameSpace))
        {
           //rssItem.Comments = Comments
            rsscomment.wpCmtId = Convert.ToInt32(commentNode.SelectSingleNode("wp:comment_id", nameSpace).InnerText);
            rsscomment.wpCmtAuthor = commentNode.SelectSingleNode("wp:comment_author", nameSpace).InnerText;
            rsscomment.wpCmtContent = commentNode.SelectSingleNode("wp:comment_content", nameSpace).InnerText;  
        }
    }
    oXMLListResult.listOfXMLResult = objrssItem;
}
```

i have xml like [enter link description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ksSwS.png)

when I am trying to read for each item in channel with xmlnode and its working fine. and each item has multiple comments which trying to achieve by using foreach inside foreach. But wp:comment foreach item its not working. What am i doing wrong? I did some google but no luck.

Thanks.

Comment: This question reminds me of those chain email jokes where you have to scroll down several pages to see the punchline. Could you remove some of the whitespace?

Comment: that white space is image file.

Comment: then maybe you should crop the image file : P

Comment: Or better yet... post the actual XML text and not a screenshot of it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
XmlNode cNode = doc.SelectSingleNode("rss/channel/item");
```

This is resetting your `item` enumeration to the beginning, which would cause every item to have identical comments.

EDIT:
I believe this is the easiest way to fix the problem I mentioned. By searching below the already selected node, you avoid the repetition. Note that `cNode` is no longer required.

```
foreach (XmlNode commentNode in itemNode.SelectNodes("wp:comment", nameSpace))
```